# PyTorch: NVIDIA NGC image or Docker Hub image?

Tags: docker, pytorch, nvidia

What are the differences between [the official PyTorch image on Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/pytorch/pytorch) and [the PyTorch image on NVIDIA NGC](https://ngc.nvidia.com/catalog/containers/nvidia:pytorch)?

The NGC page is more documented than the Docker Hub page, which has no description. But the NGC image is also heavier by a few gigabytes, and it seems to require a CUDA 10.2-compatible driver.

Is there any advantage in using the NVIDIA NGC image instead of the one from Docker Hub?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not a docker expert.
To the best of my knowledge Nvidia puts a lot of effort to ship GPU-optimized containers such that running GPU pytorch on Nvidia GPU with Nvidia container should have best possible performance.
Therefore, if you are using Nvidia hardware you should expect better performance using NGC containers. The gap, though, might not be that significant.

Answer (score 0):

nvidia said clearly on the webpage of NGC pytorch:

> The PyTorch NGC Container is optimized to run on NVIDIA DGX Foundry and NVIDIA DGX SuperPOD managed by NVIDIA Base Command Platform.

so unless u using DGX, either is fine